# System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation. (CIL/MSIL)

Tags: .net, clr, haxe, cil

I am attempting to write a toy CLR compiler for an existing language (Haxe).

When you assign a local/variable to a method (e.g. `var x:String->Void = System.Console.WriteLine`), it creates a wrapper for the pointer that looks like this in CIL:

```
 .class nested private auto ansi beforefieldinit
    $hx_FuncPtr_1
      extends [mscorlib]System.Object
  {

    .field private method void *(string) _staticptr

    .field private method instance void *(string) _instanceptr

    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void
      .ctor(
        method void *(string) staticPtr,
        method instance void *(string) instancePtr
      ) cil managed
    {
      .maxstack 8

      IL_0000: ldarg.s      this
      IL_0002: call         instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()

      // [84 9 - 84 36]
      IL_0007: ldarg.s      this
      IL_0009: ldarg.s      staticPtr
      IL_000b: stfld        method void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_staticptr

      // [85 9 - 85 40]
      IL_0010: ldarg.s      this
      IL_0012: ldarg.s      instancePtr
      IL_0014: stfld        method instance void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_instanceptr
      IL_0019: nop
      IL_001a: ret

    } // end of method $hx_FuncPtr_1::.ctor

    .method public hidebysig instance void
      invoke(
        string arg0
      ) cil managed
    {
      .maxstack 8

      IL_0000: ldarg.s      arg0
      IL_0002: ldarg.s      this
      IL_0004: ldfld        method void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_staticptr
      IL_0009: brfalse.s    IL_001a

      // [94 11 - 94 40]
      IL_000b: ldarg.s      this
      IL_000d: ldfld        method void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_staticptr
      IL_0012: calli        void (string)
      IL_0017: nop

      IL_0018: br.s         IL_0032

      // [98 11 - 98 41]
      IL_001a: ldarg.s      this
      IL_001c: ldfld        method instance void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_instanceptr
      IL_0021: brfalse.s    IL_0032

      // [101 11 - 101 42]
      IL_0023: ldarg.s      this
      IL_0025: ldfld        method instance void *(string) Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::_instanceptr
      IL_002a: calli        instance void (string)
      IL_002f: nop

      IL_0030: br.s         IL_0032
      IL_0032: nop

      // [99 13 - 99 20]
      IL_0033: ret

    } // end of method $hx_FuncPtr_1::invoke
  } // end of class $hx_FuncPtr_1
```

Then it calls the constructor of this wrapper (passing in the underlying method pointer described by the assignment; if it is an instance method, it is passed as the second parameter, if it is a static method, it is passed as the first parameter, then when `invoke` is called on the wrapper, it will call `calli` with the correct calling convention based on which pointer is not null)

This seems all fine and well (I guess, to anyone that doesn't 100% know the actual internal workings of CLR, like myself), but when I actually call the `invoke` method, I get:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.
   at Test.Test.$hx_FuncPtr_1.invoke(String arg0)
   at Test.Test.main()
```

Here is Test.Test.main:

```
 .method public hidebysig static void
    main() cil managed
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    .locals init (
      [0] int32 index,
      [1] class [mscorlib]System.Exception ex,
      [2] class Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure testMainHxClosure,
      [3] class Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_0 V_3,
      [4] bool flag,
      [5] string V_5,
      [6] string str
    )

    // [15 7 - 15 104]
    IL_0000: newobj       instance void Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.s      testMainHxClosure
    IL_0007: ldstr        "FuncRight? {0}"
    IL_000c: stloc.s      V_5

    // [16 7 - 16 35]
    IL_000e: ldstr        "Hello, World!"
    IL_0013: stloc.s      str

    // [17 7 - 17 23]
    IL_0015: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0016: stloc.s      flag

    // [21 7 - 21 170]
    IL_0018: ldloc.s      testMainHxClosure
    IL_001a: ldftn        void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string, object)
    IL_0020: ldnull
    IL_0021: newobj       instance void Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_0::.ctor(method void *(string, object), method instance void *(string, object))
    IL_0026: stfld        class Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_0 Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::doCall

    // [25 7 - 25 180]
    IL_002b: ldloc.s      testMainHxClosure
    IL_002d: ldnull
    IL_002e: ldloc.s      testMainHxClosure
    IL_0030: ldvirtftn    instance void Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::$anon_2(string)
    IL_0036: newobj       instance void Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::.ctor(method void *(string), method instance void *(string))
    IL_003b: stfld        class Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1 Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::funcRight
    .try
    {

      // [28 9 - 28 19]
      IL_0040: ldloc.s      flag
      IL_0042: brfalse.s    IL_0070

      // [30 14 - 30 27]
      IL_0044: ldc.i4       0 // 0x00000000
      IL_0049: stloc.s      index
      // start of loop, entry point: IL_004b

        // [30 29 - 30 40]
        IL_004b: ldc.i4       10 // 0x0000000a
        IL_0050: ldloc.s      index
        IL_0052: beq          IL_006d

        // [31 11 - 31 50]
        IL_0057: ldloc.s      testMainHxClosure
        IL_0059: ldfld        class Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1 Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::funcRight
        IL_005e: ldloc.s      str
        IL_0060: callvirt     instance void Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::invoke(string)

        // [30 42 - 30 59]
        IL_0065: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0066: ldloc.s      index
        IL_0068: add
        IL_0069: stloc.s      index

        IL_006b: br.s         IL_004b
      // end of loop
      IL_006d: br.s         IL_0071
      IL_006f: nop
      IL_0070: nop
      IL_0071: leave.s      IL_008a
    } // end of .try
    catch [mscorlib]System.Exception
    {

      // [33 7 - 33 27]
      IL_0073: stloc.s      ex

      // [35 9 - 35 58]
      IL_0075: ldloc.s      testMainHxClosure
      IL_0077: ldfld        class Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1 Test.Test/$Test_main_HxClosure::funcRight
      IL_007c: ldloc.s      ex
      IL_007e: callvirt     instance string [mscorlib]System.Exception::ToString()
      IL_0083: callvirt     instance void Test.Test/$hx_FuncPtr_1::invoke(string)

      IL_0088: leave.s      IL_008a
    } // end of catch
    IL_008a: nop

    // [29 11 - 29 18]
    IL_008b: ret

  } // end of method Test::main
```

[This](https://pastebin.com/qPmRMaqa) is the entire program's CIL assembly.

This is the source code... it is in Haxe language.. probably less useful, but will give you a concise idea of exactly what the program is trying to accomplish:

```
package test;

class Test {
    public static function main() {
        var y = "FuncRight? {0}";
        var t = "Hello, World!";
        var cond = true;
        var doCall:(String,cs.system.Object)->Void = cs.system.Console.WriteLine;
        function doCall2(gg:String) {
            doCall("Foo {0}", gg);
        }
        var funcRight = function(text:String) {
            doCall("funcRight? {0}", text);
        };
        try {
            if(cond) for(i in 0...10) funcRight(t);
        } catch(e:cs.system.Exception) {
            funcRight(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The function pointer wrapper seemed to work fine when I assumed only one kind of pointer (e.g. the wrapper is either for static or for instance calls) but I wanted to put them into one type so as to avoid using an interface (I eventually wanted to make the wrapper a struct, so that it would use `call` instead of `callvirt`).

Anyways, I am at a loss, any help would be greatly appreciated!

(apologies in advance for formatter dying on `Test.Test.main`...)

Comment: Could this be because method pointer types are not nullable by default in CLR... hm.. will try making them nullable to see what happens.

Comment: Does [PEVerify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool) (for classic .NET Framework) or [ILVerify](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-ilverify/6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5) (for .NET Core / .NET 5+) give a more specific error?

Comment: @joe Sewell peverify didn't do much but complain about function pointers (does the same for C# 9.0 func ptrs), have to try ILVerify. As you can imagine it's hard to find time for this so it may be a while but I will eventually update this with that info